# Specifying multiple simultaneous output formats in knitr (new)

Tags: r, yaml, knitr, r-markdown

Can I write a YAML header to produce multiple output formats for an R Markdown file using knitr? I could not reproduce the functionality described in the answer for [the original question with this title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078572/specifying-multiple-simultaneous-output-formats-in-knitr).

This markdown file:

```
---
title: "Multiple output formats"
output: 
    pdf_document: default
    html_document:
      keep_md: yes
---

# This document should be rendered as an html file and as a pdf file
```

produces a pdf file but no HTML file.

And this file:

```
---
title: "Multiple output formats"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
  pdf_document: default
---

# This document should be rendered as an html file and as a pdf file
```

produces an HTML file (and an md file) but no pdf file.

This latter example was the solution given to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078572/specifying-multiple-simultaneous-output-formats-in-knitr). I have tried knitting with Shift-Ctrl-K and with the Knit button in RStudio, as well as calling `rmarkdown::render`, but only a single output format is created, regardless of the method I use to generate the output file.

Possibly related, but I could not identify solutions:

- [How do I produce R package vignettes in multiple formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214524/how-do-i-produce-r-package-vignettes-in-multiple-formats)
- [Render all vignette formats #1051](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1051)
- [knitr::pandoc can't create pdf and tex files with a single config #769](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/769)
- [Multiple formats for pandoc #547](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/547)
- An allusion to multiple output format support in a [three year old RStudio blog post](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/06/18/r-markdown-v2/#comment-10813)

Using R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21), knitr 1.14, Rmarkdown 1.3

Comment: Where does the `(new)` in your title refer to? Is that a special version of `knitr` like `NT` in `Windows NT`

Comment: @Anthon the parenthetical "new" refers to the fact this question has the same title as a previously asked (and answered) question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I actually briefly mentioned in [Render all vignette formats #1051](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1051) and you missed it:

```
rmarkdown::render('your.Rmd', output_format = 'all')
```

It is documented on the help page `?rmarkdown::render`.

Comment: I can confirm this works, although _all_ the desired formats do still need to be in the YAML header. If I only include `output: html_document` or skip the `output` specification entirely, it only produces an HTML document. I was expecting knitr to use all the information in the YAML header without additional specification on my part. Without trying to change `rmarkdown::render` default parameters (not sure if this is possible?), it sounds like this solution requires explicit use of `rmarkdown::render`, meaning the Shift-Ctrl-K shortcut will still only produce one output format, right?

Comment: Right. You cannot Ctrl + Shift + K.

Comment: you can, using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53280491/1870254

Comment: This may also be of help if using quarto:  https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/authoring/rstudio.html

Answer (score 4):

Notwithstanding Yihui Xie's authoritative answer, and with due respect to the author of a great package, there are many cases in which `output_format = 'all'` is sub-optimal.
One of the issues that this solution raises is that the R script is re-processed from scratch *for each format*. Proof:

```
 rmarkdown::render("new.Rmd", output_format = c("html_document", "pdf_document"))


processing file: new.spin.Rmd
  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................                       |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: new.knit.md

"C:/Users/fabrn/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS new.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output new.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\fabrn\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\fabrn\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\fabrn\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\fabrn\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW6Vban\rmarkdown-str3490247b1f1e.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" 

Output created: new.html


processing file: new.spin.Rmd
  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................                       |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: new.knit.md

"C:/Users/fabrn/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS new.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output new.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\fabrn\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\fabrn\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in"
```

This really is an issue when it comes to processing big data.
In real-world examples, I usually use latex output as a single `rmarkdown::render` output, then reprocess the `.tex` files using `pandoc` or similar tools (like `prince` for pdf). So my workflow is like:

```
 rmarkdown::render('new.R', output_format = 'latex_document')
 lapply(c("html", "pdf", ...), 
        function(form) rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("new.tex", output=paste0("new.", form)))
```

The bottom line is: all depends on your data. If small, `output_format='all'` is straightforward.
If big, you are better off with a common-ground format (latex is a good choice but html may be better in some cases) as an input to conversion tools.