# How do I knit to two formats simulateously with Quarto?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

Is it possible to create multiple output formats from a Quarto/R Markdown document at once by specifying them in the YAML header?

My guess did not work:

```
---
title: Stacked Area chart with Annotations
format: 
  - html
  - gfm
---
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this way (and suppose file name is *format_test.qmd*)

**format_test.qmd**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format:
  html: default
  gfm: default
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code
into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto 
see <https://quarto.org>.

## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will 
be generated that includes both content and the output 
of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

Then from console run this following code to generate both html and github flavoured markdown (gfm) file at once.

```r
# install.packages("quarto")

quarto::quarto_render("format_test.qmd", output_format = "all")
```

Or if you prefer using the terminal (or if you are a non R-useR) you can run the following command in the terminal,

```
quarto render format_test.qmd --to html,gfm
```

Be careful to specify multiple formats without putting any space in between i.e. type them as `html,gfm`.

And running the above command in the terminal does not require you to specify `format` yaml option in your document. So, for

**format_test.qmd**

```
---
title: "Untitled"
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code
into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto 
see <https://quarto.org>.
```

---

```
quarto render format_test.qmd --to pdf,html,gfm
```

---

will generate three files in HTML, pdf, and markdown format.

Comment: In R Markdown [you can publish to multiple formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685485/specifying-multiple-simultaneous-output-formats-in-knitr-new) by including code similar to this in the yaml header,e.g. `knit: rmarkdown::render("format_test.rmd, output_format = "all")`. It seems like you should be able to do that in Quarto as well, but just substituting `quarto::quarto_render` for `rmarkdown::render` did not work. @dufei

Comment: Quarto doesn't have such knit hooks @EmmanuelTeitelbaum

Comment: Excellent answer.  You may also wish to review the quarto documentation on this topic here:  https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/authoring/rstudio.html