# Posit Quarto: how to produce both html and gfm

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

In Posit's quarto, I'm trying to simultaneously render a gfm (Github flavoured markdown) and html.  Is this possible? This is more or less what I'm trying to achieve:

```
--- 
title: "My title"
author:
  - name: MyName
format:
  gfm
  html:
    self-contained: true
    number-sections: true
---
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I knit to two formats simulateously with Quarto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256017/how-do-i-knit-to-two-formats-simulateously-with-quarto)  I dont't believe there's any UI shortcut as of now in RStudio / VS code plugin, Quarto doc also refers to `quarto_render()` - https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/authoring/rstudio.html#rendering:~:text=If%20you%20would%20like%20to%20render,well%20as%20the%20output%20format(s).

Comment: Thanks - I didn't see it was a duplicate of the question linked.